# Can't figure out how to add a to-do item to the completed section

Tags: javascript, html

I have two to-do items hard-coded in the html document for testing purposes. I have no problem add those to items from the incomplete section to the completed section, however, when I type an item in the text field; I am not able to add the new item to the completed section via the "Complete" button. I have searched on google for the answer for some time now, but I'm really not even sure what I would search for to get the answer to my problem. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you. Here is my code...

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
  // Get a task from the user
  var addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
    
  // To hold a task
  var task;
    
  var createButton = function(){
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("class", "completeButton");
    button.setAttribute("name", "completeButton");
    button.innerHTML = "Complete";
    
    return button;
  };
    
  var completeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('completeButton'); 
    
  addButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the task
    task = document.getElementById('task');
    
    var taskNumber = 2;
    
    // Add a task to the uncompleted list
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(task.value);
    var button = createButton();
    button.setAttribute("id", (taskNumber + 1));
    var listElement = document.createElement("LI");
    listElement.appendChild(textNode);
    listElement.appendChild(button);
    document.getElementById('uncompleted-list').appendChild(listElement);
    
    // Clear the text field
    task.value = "";
    
    completeButtons[taskNumber] = button;
      
  });
    
  // Mark a task as complete
    
  // console.log(completeButtons);
    
  for (var i = 0; i < completeButtons.length; i++) {
    completeButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    
      var task = this.parentElement;
      task.parentElement.removeChild(task);
    
      // Remove the complete button
      task.removeChild(task.lastChild);
    
      // Add a task to the completed list
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(task.innerHTML);
      var listElement = document.createElement("LI");
      listElement.appendChild(textNode);
      document.getElementById('completed-list').appendChild(listElement);
    
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>ToDo App</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    
    
            <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
              <h1>ToDo App</h1>
            </header>
    
            <form id="task-form" action="index.html" method="post">
              <label for="task">Enter a task:</label>
              <input type="text" name="task" id="task" value="Get milk...">
              <button type="button" name="addButton" id="addButton">Add</button>
            </form>
    
            <div class="list-boxes">
              <h2>Incomplete Tasks</h2>
              <ul id="uncompleted-list">
                <li>Pay rent <button type="button" name="completeButton" class="completeButton" id="1">Complete</button></li>
                <li>Buy groceries <button type="button" name="completeButton" class="completeButton" id="2">Complete</button></li>
                <!--<li>Get milk <a href="#"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></li>-->
              </ul>
            </div>
    
            <div class="list-boxes">
              <h2>Completed Tasks</h2>
              <ul  id="completed-list">
                <li>Feed cats</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
    
            <script src="scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

**The new "Complete" buttons that are created are not bound to your custom `click` handler.**

This is because your `for` loop near the bottom of the JavaScript runs *only once*, right at the initialization of your file. This is fine, except that the code will not apply to any *new* buttons that are created by the "Add" button. To fix this, I made sure to bind new buttons to the same `click` function, as soon as they are created. See my comments in the JavaScript below.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');

  var task;

  var createButton = function() {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("class", "completeButton");
    button.setAttribute("name", "completeButton");
    button.innerHTML = "Complete";
    // Manually bind this new button to the function "moveToComplete"
    button.addEventListener("click", moveToComplete);

    return button;
  };

  var completeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('completeButton');

  // Make sure to include "event" as a parameter if you intend to use it
  addButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    task = document.getElementById('task');

    var taskNumber = 2;

    var textNode = document.createTextNode(task.value);
    var button = createButton();
    button.setAttribute("id", (taskNumber + 1));
    var listElement = document.createElement("LI");
    listElement.appendChild(textNode);
    listElement.appendChild(button);
    document.getElementById('uncompleted-list').appendChild(listElement);

    task.value = "";

    completeButtons[taskNumber] = button;

  });
  
  var moveToComplete = function() {
    var task = this.parentElement;
    task.parentElement.removeChild(task);

    task.removeChild(task.lastChild);

    var textNode = document.createTextNode(task.innerHTML);
    var listElement = document.createElement("LI");
    listElement.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById('completed-list').appendChild(listElement);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < completeButtons.length; i++) {
    // I have abstracted out the function to "moveToComplete" (see above)
    completeButtons[i].addEventListener("click", moveToComplete);
  }
});
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>ToDo App</h1>
</header>

<form id="task-form" action="index.html" method="post">
  <label for="task">Enter a task:</label>
  <input type="text" name="task" id="task" value="Get milk...">
  <button type="button" name="addButton" id="addButton">Add</button>
</form>

<div class="list-boxes">
  <h2>Incomplete Tasks</h2>
  <ul id="uncompleted-list">
    <li>Pay rent <button type="button" name="completeButton" class="completeButton" id="1">Complete</button></li>
    <li>Buy groceries <button type="button" name="completeButton" class="completeButton" id="2">Complete</button></li>
    <!--<li>Get milk <a href="#"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></li>-->
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-boxes">
  <h2>Completed Tasks</h2>
  <ul id="completed-list">
    <li>Feed cats</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Now it's throwing an exception in my moveToComplete function saying that parentElement is undefined in the statement task = this.parentElement.

Comment: @JasonDelgado hmm, how about now? I moved the `moveToComplete` function above the `for` loop.